# Improvements in JavaScript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a train station text effect.

You can see here what i have achieved so far: http://www.jaspreetkaur.com/chatter/

here's the code, for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/ARhvu/

Issues:

1. The effect is running very slow, not giving it a very smooth and realistic effect.
2. Not working in IE7
3. I think the script i have created can be improved.

Please provide your expert advise to resolve the issues.

Thanks :)

---

Update:

The script is for the animation of text "Get to the chatter that matters"

Following is the Javascript code i have used:

`$(document).ready(function() {`

```
var newSrt = '';
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] != ' ') {
        newSrt += '<span>'+str[i]+'</span>';
        //newSrt += '<span> </span>';
    } else {
        newSrt += '<span class="nobg">'+str[i]+'</span>';
        //newSrt += '<span class="nobg"> </span>';
    }
}
$('.animate').html(newSrt);


scroll();
```

});

```
var str = ('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog').toUpperCase();
var symtype=new Array(" ","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");

var symarray=new Array();

for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){ symarray[i]=" "; }

function scroll(){
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        if (symarray[i]!=str.substring(i,i+1)) {
            for (var x=0; x<symtype.length; x++) {
                if (symarray[i]==symtype[x]) {
                    symarray[i]=symtype[x+1];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        $('.animate').find('span').eq(i).html(symarray[i]);    
    }

    setTimeout('scroll()',10);

}
```

I hope this describes the code batter.

---

**Update 2**

Script is working in IE7 now, it's too fast on all browsers, i can make it slow by changing the setTimeout, but it's too slow in Firefox (only), I am using Firefox 9.0.1

---

**Update 3**

Surprisingly firebug is making the script slow in Firefox, turning firebug off, resolves the speed issue in Firefox.

in IE7 issue is related to CSS, which i think i will be able to resolve.

The only think left is to improve the script to make it reusable for other places in the website.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A couple of issues with your question: 1. It's too broad. SO is best suited to helping you deal with *specific* issues (like it being too slow, for instance). 2. Please always post the relevant code and markup *in the question itself*; why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: And, when we go to your chatter page, tell us what we're looking for or what we need to do to cause the thing you want us to see.  Remember, we've NEVER seen your page before and don't know what it's supposed to do or what we're supposed to look for.  I've been to your site and don't know what you want me to see.  I don't see any animations.

Comment: It doesn't seem slow on my computer, in fact, it may be a little too fast. Maybe it has to do with your browser or system configuration?

Comment: @jfriend00: I believe the OP is referring to the flipping characters that eventually form the text "GET TO THE CHATTER THAT MATTERS".

Comment: And, the jsFiddle you posted doesn't run (there is a JS error in the console) so we can't see it run there either.

Comment: that animation runs so fast on my computer I can't even see it

Comment: Fixed the jsFiddle here so it works now: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VWXFp/ and slowed it down a bit as it went way too fast on my computer.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yours works in IE as well. I guess you should post it as an answer with an explanation of what changes you made

Comment: @xbonez - I make an answer out of my fixes.  Also found a major performance improvement which could have been partially responsible for slowdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed up your jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VWXFp/ to make it run and it appears to work now, even in IE.

1. I moved the `$(document).ready()` block to the end so the globals are defined first which was only required because of the way you had the jsFiddle configured.
2. I changed to `setTimeout(scroll,100);` to use the direct function reference rather than a text string.
3. I changed the timeout vale on the timer to 100ms
4. I changed the jsFiddle setting in the upper left to "no wrap (body)"
5. I changed your letter setting loop to be massively more efficient.  You were re-finding ever single letter span for every single letter rather than finding them all once and just looping through them.  This could have been a performance issue in some browsers.

For #5, I changed from this:

```
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    $('.animate').find('span').eq(i).html(symarray[i]);    
}
```

to this:

```
$('.animate').find('span').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).html(symarray[index]);
});
```

Which evaluates `$('.animate').find('span')` only once instead of `str.length` times.

Comment: Found a major performance improvement and added that to my answer as item #5.